# get one result from a query

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I tried doing this,

```
//returns the last updated id
$val = $DB->GetOne("SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
```

But it doesn't work unless I do `$DB->GetRow()`. So, does this mean that I need to have where clause for the `GetOne()` to work?

Comment: we don't know what code you are using

Comment: As in, what library are you using that creates the $DB object? What class is $DB an instance of?

Comment: @Michael -- thanks for adding the tag; that's helpful.

Comment: @Matt I didn't add it - I thought it was already there.

Comment: @Matt, I had added it when I posted the question. Any luck on the answer? I am trying different ways, surprised to see it not working!

Comment: @Michael, Negative... see revision two: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9200603/2

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Is there an error thrown? If not, what exactly do you get from `var_dump($val);` afterwards?

Comment: @Nikhil Has my answer helped you out at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that since you are querying for one result, the `WHERE` clause is essential.  If you attempt to get one result without defining what you are looking for, then I don't imagine it will work in the way you intend.  Refer to the [PHP Code Examples](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) from the ADOdb documentation.

Comment: I pull data with WHERE without conditions all the time, it just fetches the entire row set using the ordering you told it to use or it defaulted to, this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @OhMrBigshot Sorry. I meant assignment, not condition.  Secondly, I think he's just trying to get **one** result, not an entire row.  I would imagine using a method with the name `GetOne()` would mean he wants one result??... I'm confused.  His question isn't word very well.

Comment: Looks to me like he just wants one row from many D: I'm not sure

Comment: @OhMrBigshot But referring to the link I provided in my answer, it appears the `$val` is used to retrieve one value.  Yeah, I'm not too sure either...

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question will work but there was a bug in the adodb mysql driver where it will return false (instead of NULL) when no results are found. [The bug was fixed](http://phplens.com/lens/lensforum/msgs.php?id=18407) in 2010 . So you may be experiencing the bug if you're running an old version of adodb.

GetOne returns the content of the first field in the first row of the result set.

Also saying "it's not working" doesn't say much.

Try printing $DB->ErrorMsg() to see what's wrong.